# How do I increment the value of an input of type=number using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I'm trying to increment the value of an `input type="number"` element using `jQuery`. However I currently have it so that every time I press the add button it appends 1 to the value so I get a value like `1111` etc etc...

I was able to do it fine when it was set to `type=text` but it was not ideal as I was trying to increment the values so all that was happening was the counter was being appended to the value of the input box. Output was like this `01 02 03 04`.

Currently, I'm doing this:

### HTML

```
<input type="number" class="qty" id="book-qty"  disabled/>
<span class="add">ADD</span>
```

### jQuery

```
var count = 0;
$('.minus').click(function () {

    if (count - 1 >= 0) {
        count = parseInt($(this).parent().find('#book-qty').val());
        count = count - 1;
    $(this).parent().find('#book-qty').val(count);
    } else {
        alert('Nothing to take away!');
    }
});
$('.add').click(function () {
    count = $(this).parent().find('#book-qty').val();
    count = count + 1;
    $(this).parent().find('#book-qty').val(count);
});
```

I have a JSFiddle I'm working on here:

https://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/L1sLr921/

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L1sLr921/3/)

you need to parse the value to an integer otherwise it get treated as a string so it will concatenate instead of add together.

```
count = parseInt($('#book-qty').val());
```

Also you need to specify a default value for your inputs like stated by Mex.

Comment: Don't forget the radix.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default value to 0 with "value=0" on the input type=number.

Then use:

```
count = parseInt(count) + 1;
```

instead of:

```
count = count + 1;
```

Comment: Don't forget the radix.

Comment: But will the string retrieved from the value of the input type=number ever have a 0 on the front to be unintentionally interpreted as base 8?